# how to add the address as N/A if the address field coming as null .otherwise shows as Address

Tags: angular

i have a scenario where i need to show the info in viewinfo popup, if the address field is null at that time address field is showing as empty, but i dont need to show like this i need to show N/A. the problem is i dont have separate fields in html to write the if condition,

```
       <mat-list role="list">
        <div *ngFor="let tcolumn of tableColumns;let i = index"> 
     <div fxFlex *ngIf="component=='Users'">
            <mat-list-item style="min-height: 60px;" role="listitem">
              <div style="width: 31%; float:left;"><b>{{columnName[i]}}</b></div>
              <div style="width: 50%; float:right;" *ngIf="selectedData || tcolumn !== ''">{{ tcolumn != 'locationsRoles' ? selectedData[tcolumn] :''}}</div>
              <div fxFlex class="layout_role"Flexlayout="column" *ngIf="tcolumn== 'locationsRoles'">
                <span *ngFor="let lnr of selectedData[tcolumn]"><b class="location">Location :</b> {{lnr.location.name.split("-").length>1 ? lnr.location.name.split("-").splice(1): lnr.location.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                  <span class="role">
                    <b>Roles: </b>
                    <span *ngFor="let r of lnr.role; let isLast=last">{{r.name}}{{isLast ? '' : ','}} </span><br>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </mat-list-item>
          </div>
```

ts

```
  /**viewInfo */
  viewInfo(selectedRow) {
    this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      'selectedValue': this.selectedRow,
      'tableColumns': this.displayedColumns,
      'columnName': ['First Name :', 'Last Name :', 'User Name :', 'Client :',' Address'],
      "component": "Users",
      "mode": true,
    }
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ViewInfoComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
  public displayedColumns=['firstName','lastName','username','tenantName','address','locationsRoles']
```

viewinfo.ts

````
  if (data) {
      if(data.selectedValue.cell) this.gridSelectedData = data.selectedValue.cell;
      this.selectedData = data.selectedValue;
      this.mode = data.mode;
      this.component = data.component;
      this.columnName = data.columnName;
      this.tableColumns = data.tableColumns;
    }
  }
```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I791e.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ternary operator in html
like this

```
{{ tcolumn != 'locationsRoles' ? selectedData[tcolumn]==null?'N/A':selectedData[tcolumn]:''}}
```